# C++ backend with SQLite on Android - main app and widget not synced

Tags: android, c, sqlite

I have C/C++ app on Android that initialize SQLite via `sqlite3_open_v2`. The app has a bunch of widgets available. When the user adds the widget, it opens its own database instance with a different call to `sqlite3_open_v2`. Basically I have two database connections from two different processes. Each of them opens connection with the following flags

My init database method looks like this:

```
sqlite3* dbInit(const char* filePath) {

    sqlite3_shutdown();

    int threadSafe = sqlite3_threadsafe();

    if (threadSafe == 1){
         sqlite3_config(SQLITE_CONFIG_SERIALIZED);
    }
    
    sqlite3 *db = nullptr;
    sqlite3_open_v2(filePath, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_FULLMUTEX | SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nullptr);

    return db;
}
```

The `db` instance is wrapper inside a class, using `shared_ptr` (one in app, one in widget).

Now the problem is, when adding the widget, some information may be missing, so the user is redirected to the app when a user updates data, resulting in a database change (I confirm this by doing select and printing data).
Then, the user uses the back button and returns to the widget setup. However, trying to read data from the database results in the same result as before opening the app. There are no data.

Is there some cache mechanism, so that the data are not written to the database file?
Or the other way around, running the same select will result in reading from some cache query?